# Can an app using OAuth 1.0 be listed on Google Apps Marketplace v2.0?

Tags: oauth, google-apps-marketplace

Does GAMv2 support apps using OAuth 1.0, or for any app to be listed on GAMv2 it has to use OAuth 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

It must use oauth2.  Please see this quote in the approval form:"OAuth2.0 is required, if your application does not use it please do not publish your application as it will be rejected."

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/14QOb8PbSLKDgwIp8Zv-luoAAVurPXUqtzL0Hgikp3rk/viewform